# Dictionary.py def load(): mixes up variables

Tags: python

Okay when putting words in the dict() the words are fun but after they are loaded again the dict() items are all jumbled around.

```
   def load():
      dWord = {}
     for word in open("Dictionary.DB","r").readlines():
        if len(word.strip())>0:
           raw = word.split()
           word, name, numdef, definition, wordtime = ' '.join(raw[0:-4]), raw[1], raw[2], ' '.join(raw[3:-1]), raw[-1]
           dWord[word] = name, int(numdef), definition, int(wordtime)
     Dictionary.dWord = dWord
```

Is there a way to keep the dict() items from mixing up with each other?

Comment: Do you mean that you want it to not reorder and keep the order in which you filled it?

Comment: Yeah exactly that. xD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict), use it just like normal dict:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> d = OrderedDict()
>>> d[2] = 3
>>> d[1] = 4
>>> d[5] = 2
>>> print d
OrderedDict([(2, 3), (1, 4), (5, 2)])
>>> for i in d:
>>>     print i
2
1
5
```

As you see it keeps the insertion order.

Comment: So d would be the same as dWord. So it would be dWord = OrderedDict() right?

Comment: Alright. Because last time I used two ' '.join(raws it caused all the items to become mixed up.

Comment: Is it OK now with OrderedDict? Is your problem solved?

Comment: Kinda. I'm a bit confused on how to use it. Could you explain how to please?

Comment: Just replace `dword = {}` with `dword = OrderedDict()` @user3103923

Comment: That's actually pretty easy xD