# def load() in dictionary jumbles variables when using spaces

Tags: python

Ok everytime I reload the dict() it causes the items to get jumbled because I am trying to use spaces in the dict items.

```
  def load():
      dWord = {} # dict
      for word in open("Dictionary.DB","r").readlines():
         if len(word.strip())>0:
            raw = word.split()
            word, name, definition, wordtime = ' '.join(raw[0:-3]), raw[1], ' '.join(raw[2:-1]), raw[-1]
             dWord[word] = name, definition, int(wordtime)
      Dictionary.dWord = dWord
```

The word and definition uses spaces.
What it looks like in the file before the def load():

```
test word charles this is a test 1389611260
```

Before using def load():

```
{'test word': ('charles', 'this is a test',  138965430)}
```

Example of after using def load():

```
{'test word charles this is': ('word', 'charles this is a test', 1389655439)}
```

File after the def load():

```
test word charles this is word charles this is a test 1389655469
```

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: Can you provide an example line or `raw` list?

Comment: This looks a lot like [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21086786/78845)!

Comment: The problem is that after using def load(): it causes all the variables to mix into each other and scramble everything.

Comment: Is it just me, or is there a stray space before `dWord[word] = ...`?

Comment: @tobias_k the after and before of using def load():  are the example.

Comment: If "before" is an example for a line in the file, then where did all those brackets and quotes go?

Comment: A stray space? What do you mean?

Comment: Given that format, there is _just no way_ to unambiguously split the string. At least you'll have to add some delimiters, like in CSV, but then you can just as well use the `csv` module in the first place, or even better, since you are using a dictionary, `json`, as suggested by @Alfe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you store a dictionary in a stringified version in a text file and then fail to parse it properly because on saving you remove vital information (where values start and end for example).

I propose to use a library for keeping the values intact.  You should consider using JSON for a task like this then you won't have to parse everything yourself and can still read the test file:

```
import json

# store your value:
with open('file.txt', 'w') as outFile:
  json.dump(dWord, outfile)

# read your value:
with open('file.txt') as inFile:
  dword = json.load(inFile)
```

Comment: I really dislike json in my opinion

Comment: And why, if I may ask?  You could use pickle or marshal or whatever you prefer.  But you won't get happy using your own buggy implementation :-/  And solving all the issues with that will let you end at sth similar to using json in the first place.  So what's the reason for your dislike of json?

Comment: I struggle using it >.> and I don't think it'll work on my DB file.

Comment: Of course it won't work on your DB file.  Are you stuck with the format of your DB file?  And if so, are you sure your DB file format contains all the information necessary to rebuild the dictionary?  I still fear it does not contain the information to figure out where which value starts and ends, but I might be mistaken.

Comment: It might be the format. Yeah it might know where each value starts and ends. Before when I wasn't trying to get the word to be more than one word it worked fine but after using another ' '.join(raw[0-3]) it caused that error.

Comment: Maybe you should post the code which _creates_ the DB file as well because I feel the problem lies within there.  If the example above results in a DB file entry like `test word charles this is a test 138965430` then there is no way to find out how these words were grouped in the first place.  It could have been `{'test word': ('charles', 'this is a test',  138965430)}` as well as `{'test word charles': ('this is', 'a test',  138965430)}` and several others.

Comment: It might not know where to each value to start and to where it ends.*

Comment: I have the whole module in this if it's helpful http://bpaste.net/show/167551

Comment: Yeah, and if that format does not specify that precisely yet, then you will have to introduce quoting to make that clear.  And that will lead you to something very similar than json.

Comment: Yeah, as I expected, that line `DB.append(a+" "+str(b)+" "+str(c)+" "+str(d))` actually _removes_ the information where each value starts and ends.  The delimiter (space) can also appear _within_ the values, and then you have no way of finding out which space is a delimiter and which is part of a value.  You could choose a different delimiter (e. g. `|` or `#`) if you can ensure that these won't appear in the values.

Comment: But if you _cannot_ ensure that for any character, then you should do a proper quoting, and that would surely be close to using json in the first place (which I still recommend).

Comment: Can I use spaces on the word though if I use json?

Comment: Yeah, of course. JSON can store dictionaries containing dicts, strings, lists, and combinations thereof without problems.  (And read them in again later ;-)  Only the distinction between lists and tuples will get lost (but you don't seem to have that anyway).

Comment: Ah I see xD. I will try an attempt at switching my stuff to json then.

Comment: I'm already lost on how to do it xD

Comment: See my answer to find the minimal code on how to store and how to read a value using json.  It is extremely simple.

Comment: But what do I change in my code and where do I put that exactly in the code?

Comment: For reading just use this:  `with open("Dictionary.DB") as inFile: Dictionary.dWord = json.load(inFile)`.  You can replace the whole function you posted by this single line (though I recommend to split it after the colon in to two lines as I did in my answer above).

Comment: For writing you can change your `save` method to do just this: `with open("Dictionary.DB", "w") as outFile: json.dump(Dictionary.dWord, outFile)`.  That's it.

Comment: Ah thanks that does look easier xD

Comment: Ah I just got a major error on the json decoder.

Comment: Of course you have to _write_ a json file before you _read_ it.  Did you try to json-read your DB file as it is in the old version?

Comment: Well I deleted the DB file and started a new one with your save() and load()

Comment: I'm using this    if not os.path.exists("Dictionary.DB"):
  open("Dictionary.DB","w").write("")

Comment: You should use `if not os.path.exists("Dictionary.DB"):`, `with open("Dictionary.DB","w") as outFile:`, `json.dump({}, outFile)` to create an empty version of the DB file because an empty file is not a valid json file.